# Send Bird didReceiveMessage Not Works

Tags: objective-c, sendbird

so created a simple application to test out sendbird services, they look best, so i have read their documentation, and at this moment. i made something.. and i got a problem there, when do i have to call the didReceiveMessage or why mine is not working?

myCode

```
    - (IBAction)connnect:(id)sender {


    [SBDOpenChannel getChannelWithUrl:@"iDict" completionHandler:^(SBDOpenChannel * _Nullable channel, SBDError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error 1 : %@", error.localizedDescription);
            return;
        }

        [channel enterChannelWithCompletionHandler:^(SBDError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                return;
            }
            NSLog(@"Connected to Channel : %@",channel.channelUrl);



            // ...
        }];
    }];


}

- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender {

    [self.channel sendUserMessage:@"pop" data:@"Hey" completionHandler:^(SBDUserMessage * _Nullable userMessage, SBDError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            return;


        }

    }];
}



- (void)channel:(SBDBaseChannel * _Nonnull)sender didReceiveMessage:(SBDBaseMessage * _Nonnull)message {
    if (sender == self.channel) {
    NSLog(@"From Button.Message Received From %@ message is : %@ in channel :",sender.description,message.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed");
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register your current class as the channel's delegate? You need to do this so that when the channel receives a message, it will call your delegate with the received message.

So in your class, I am assuming it's a UIViewController, declare it to conform to  like so:

```
@interface OpenChannelViewController : ViewController<SBDChannelDelegate>
@end
```

Somewhere in your viewDidLoad, you should add this class to the channel delegate.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [SBDMain addChannelDelegate:self identifier:UNIQUE_HANDLER_ID];
}
```

Now you should receive messages. Info was taken from here:
https://docs.sendbird.com/ios?_ga=1.152151677.594130729.1491427400#open_channel_3_receiving_messages

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate. But I did that, did a lot, what I am stocked at is the UNIQUE_HANDLER_ID I don't know what is that.